# How to put Unicode in browser title

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I would like to put unicode characters in IE's title bar (and tabs).

How do I achieve this using C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "using C#"? Not simply title of web page?

Comment: Page.Title = "//someunicode//" does not work.

Comment: Output: A sequence of little boxes.

Comment: Page.Title = "//someunicode//" will not produce boxes.  Hiding the actual string you pass and not documenting your Windows and IE version is unproductive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Page.Title = "//someunicode//"` does not work

Setting Page.Title works fine for me, assuming you're using a Unicode-capable response encoding such as the default UTF-8.

What are the characters you are trying to set exactly? Bear in mind that the page title is rendered using the operating system's window title bar font, and not the fonts set up for page HTML content, so you may have a smaller range of characters available for Title than you do for page content. If you choose characters that don't exist in the font used for title bars you may get squares.

(The same may occur for other OS-rendered elements, for example select menus in some browsers.)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be to encode your unicode string as follows:

```
Page.Title = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<some unicode />");
```

However the `<title>` tags of HTML are fairly rigid in what they take as an input. You can't for example put any more HTML in them.

There are also apparently limitations in what the standard Encoder used by HtmlEncode is capable of encoding so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Well, HTML-encoding will allow you to put any characters in the title string, but they're displayed literally as text rather than being actual active HTML. It's probably not the problem here, but in general +1 for remembering to HTML-encode Title; I consider it a pernicious bug that ASP.NET doesn't HTML-encode Title by default, especially given that it's not even possible to put other elements in `<title>`.

Answer (score 0):

What do *you* mean by "unicode characters"?

If I have a UTF-8 file with html, I can put this in it and it displays correctly:

```
<title>HTML test. TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ </title>
```

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if you show the UTF8 encoding meta tag IMHO.

Comment: ASP.NET adds the `charset` parameter to the `Content-Type` header automatically so adding the `<meta>` isn't completely necessary (though it's a good idea just in case the file gets saved, losing its Content-Type header information).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ASP.Net, you can set the response encoding of all pages on your site to UTF-8 in web.config as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Once you've done this, assigning any valid Unicode string to Page.Title should produce the expected result. You can of course also use other Unicode encodings, but UTF-8 is the most common.